# LRA motor driver activity appears to be corrupting I2C commands to another device

Tags: stm32, i2c, imu, buzzer

I'm working on a device that uses an STM32L552ZET6Q, two DRV2605L motor drivers configured for LRA PWM output, and two BNO055 IMU units configured for IMUPLUS mode.

Each of the four chips is connected to the L5 microcontroller on its own I2C bus (four buses in total), and the DRV chips are also connected to the L5 via a PWM bus. The DRV units and the L5 microcontroller are both on the same board, but there are two additional boards, each of which has an LRA motor and a BNO055 unit. They are connected to the main board via an 8-pin cable:

[image: cable looks like this]

The problem I keep running into is when I run the board with the DRV enabled, it seems to corrupt the I2C commands heading to the BNO055. If I disable the DRV (shown in `init_lra` function below), the BNO has no problems sending data.

The code for initializing the DRV can be seen below:

```
/*
 * initializes the DRV2605L for LRA PWM mode
 */

void init_LRA(struct DRV *lra)
{
    HAL_Delay(1);
    init_driver(lra);
    DRV2605_setMode(lra, DRV2605_MODE_PWMANALOG);
    HAL_Delay(1);
    writeRegister8(lra, DRV2605_REG_CONTROL3, 3);
    HAL_Delay(1);
    DRV2605_useLRA(lra);
    HAL_Delay(1);
    DRV2605_selectLibrary(lra, 6);
    HAL_Delay(1);
    writeRegister8(lra, DRV2605_REG_MODE, 0x43); //change to 0x03 to enable the DRV2605L
    //DRV2605_PWM_Start(lra);
    //smoothHaptics(lra, 65);
}
```

When I run the board with the DRV disabled, this is what I see on a logic analyzer and Tera Term:

[image: success on logic analyzer]

[image: success on Tera Term]

And when I run the board with the DRV enabled, I see this:

[image: Failure on logic analyzer]

[image: Failure on Tera Term]

This is the code being used to transmit the BNO data to Tera Term:

```
void streamSensorData(bno055 *chip)
{
    uint8_t length = 0;
    strm_cnt++;
    vector_t accel = bno055_getVectorAccelerometer(chip);
    vector_t gyro = bno055_getVectorGyroscope(chip);
    //bno055_vector_t mag = bno055_getVectorMagnetometer();
    vector_t orient = bno055_getVectorEuler(chip);
    vector_t quat = bno055_getVectorQuaternion(chip);

    if(orient.z > 0)
    {
        orient.z = 180.0 - orient.z;
    }
    else
    {
        orient.z = -180.0 - orient.z;
    }
    SaiPrev = Sai;
    RollPrev = Roll;
    Sai = orient.x;
    Roll = orient.z;

    if(strm_cnt > 10)
    {
        if (Sai - SaiPrev > 300)
        {
            Sai += -360 ;
        }

        else if (Sai - SaiPrev < -300)
        {
            Sai += 360 ;
        }
        else if (Sai - SaiPrev > 120)
        {
            Sai += -180 ;
        }
        else if (Sai - SaiPrev < -120)
        {
            Sai += 180 ;
        }

        if (Roll - RollPrev > 300)
        {
            Roll += -360 ;
        }
        else if (Roll - RollPrev < -300)
        {
            Roll += 360 ;
        }
    }

    accel.x += (2* (quat.x * -quat.z - quat.w * -quat.y)) * 9.81;
    accel.y += (2* (-quat.y * -quat.z + quat.w * quat.x)) * 9.81;
    accel.z += (2* (quat.w * quat.w + -quat.z * -quat.z - 0.5)) * 9.81;

    if (abs(accel.x) > 25)
    {
        accel.x = 0.1;
    }
    if (abs(accel.y) > 25)
    {
        accel.y = 0.1;
    }
    if (abs(accel.z) > 25)
    {
        accel.z = 0.1;
    }

    memcpy(strmBuf, "\0", strlen(strmBuf));
    length = sprintf(strmBuf, "~%0.2f#%0.2f#%0.2f#%0.2f#%0.2f#%0.2f#%0.2f#%0.2f#%0.2f#%0.2f#%0.2f#%0.2f#%0.2f~\r\n", accel.x, accel.y,
            accel.z,gyro.x, gyro.y, gyro.z,
            Sai, orient.y, Roll,quat.w, quat.x,
            quat.y, quat.z);

    CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t *)strmBuf, length);
}
```

Note that in the second image of Tera Term, that's *all* I'm seeing: that's as far as it gets before it stops printing.

My initial thought, and what others also suggested, was that the pull-ups for the BNO's I2C line needed to have lower resistance. I've since lowered them to 2 kΩ, which has improved things, but still isn't enough.

All I've been able to determine so far is that when the DRV is enabled, it sends a signal to its connected motor and the BNO stops working. The logic analyzer shows me that the address it's writing to is consistent when the DRV is disabled or not initialized at all, but gets changed at random when the DRV is enabled (normally all BNO stuff is addressed to 0x28 in my code, but the logic analyzer shows read and write commands being addressed to 0x28, 0x2C and 0x14 when the DRV is enabled).

To summarize, all the information I have points to the DRV being enabled and sending a signal to the LRA motor on the other side of the cable as the cause of the I2C commands for the BNO being corrupted while traveling through that same cable. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this? Is there any additional information from me that would be helpful?

Comment: Oscilloscope pictures from I2C bus signals might help to verify what the issue is. What length cable it is and what I2C communication speed you use? In general, I2C is not supposed to be used over cables between boards, but with careful design of the whole system (includes both boards and cable between them) it can go several meters. Have you debugged where the code hangs and why? Does any function return a status or error? Which error and what it means?

Comment: @Justme The cable is 1.5 meters. I also forgot to add that there's a different design for this that used Raspberry Pi instead of STM32 and Serial communication, and that one worked fine, and it used not just the same design, but the exact same physical boards with the BNOs on them that I'm using right now.

I have run a debug on the code and it gets frozen in the I2C Master Transmit function. I'm using HAL_MAX_DELAY for the moment.
 
Regarding oscilloscope pictures, it's not perfect, but the logic analyzer pictures show analog response as well as digital

Comment: I shouldn't say frozen, actually. It's not crashing or hard-faulting. As I remember it, it's waiting for a response from the BNO that never arrives, probably because the write command it sent out had its address shaken from 0x28 to something else, and "something else" isn't a device on the bus that can respond to it

Comment: Sounds like you need better I2C functions that time out instead of blocking indefinitely

Comment: @Bryan Well, that stops the hanging, but it doesn't stop the data from being corrupted. I've got some additional advice on that though, so I'll update this if it pans out